Distribution of coupons in the coupon collector problem
The coupon collector problem is well known: how long does it take me to collect $n$ coupons if a random coupon appears each day.
It is known that it takes me, on average, $n H_n$ days to collect all coupons. It is also known (see here) that there are on average $H_n$ coupons that I collect only once.
I would also like to know how many coupons appear $2$ times, $3$ times, and in general $x$ times. I have the feeling there should be a paper on this but I haven't found it (there is this paper but it tackles a problem in which each coupon should be collected $m$ times). Recommendations are much appreciated.

Just for clarification, you collect until you see all $n$ distinct coupon-types and then look at all the collected coupons to see how many types have appeared once, twice, three times etc.

For $n=2$ this is not difficult: the probability $1$ coupon-type appears exactly once is $\frac12$ and the probability $2$ coupon-types appear exactly once is also $\frac12$ (does the second coupon match the first or not?);  for $k>1$,  the probability $1$ coupon-type appears exactly $k$ times is $2^{-k}$ and the probability $0$ coupon-types appear exactly $k$ times is $1- 2^{-k}$ (how often does the first coupon-type seen appear before the other coupon-type appears?).

wow, have been looking for a discussion on this problem for a while!

You can basically bootstrap the result for $x=1$. This works as follows.
To show that the expected number of types (from $n$ types) collected exactly once is $H_n$, we argue that the probability that the $i$th type to appear is collected exactly once is $1/(n-i+1)$. This is because after the $i$th type first appears, there are now $n-i$ unseen types plus one type we are interested in, and that type appears again if and only if it is the last of these $n-i+1$ types to appear in the future.
Now if we try to do this for $x=2$, what happens? After the $i$th type first appears, wait until we see all the $n-i$ unseen types, plus the $i$th type again (which is just coupon collector with $n-i+1$ types). Now the $i$th type appears at most twice in the original process if and only if it appears at most once in this section. (It is at most, rather than exactly, since if it is last one to appear in this section, the section continues longer than the original process would, and actually the type only appeared once in total.) This probability we know from the previous result: it is $\frac{H_{n-i+1}}{n-i+1}$. So the overall expectation of types that appear at most twice is $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{H_{n-i+1}}{n-i+1}$, and to convert "at most" to "exactly" you just need to subtract the expected number appearing exactly once.
You can continue this argument to get a recurrence: writing $f_x(n)$ for the number of types appearing at most $x$ times, we have $f_1(n)=H_n$,
$$f_x(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{f_{x-1}(n-i+1)}{n-i+1}$$
for $x\geq 2$, and what you are interested in is $f_x(n)-f_{x-1}(n)$.

To start  let us state  the probability of  needing $m$
draws to  collect all $n$ coupons.  Using combinatorial
classes as in Analytic  Combinatorics we get with the
labeled set operator / class
$$\mathrm{P}[T=m] = \frac{1}{n^m} \times {n\choose 1}
\times (m-1)! [z^{m-1}] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}.$$
Let us  just verify  that this  will produce  $n \times
H_n$ for the number of draws. We get
$$\mathrm{E}[T] =
\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{n m}{n^m} (m-1)! [z^{m-1}] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 0} 
\frac{m+1}{n^m} m! [z^m] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 0} 
\frac{m+1}{n^m} m! [z^m] \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} 
{n-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q} \exp(qz)
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 0} 
\frac{m+1}{n^m} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} 
(-1)^{n-1-q} q^m
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q}
\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{m+1}{n^m} q^m
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q} 
\frac{1}{(1-q/n)^2}.$$
Now to evaluate this last sum we introduce
$$f(z) = (n-1)! \frac{1}{(1-z/n)^2} 
\prod_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-r}
= n! \frac{n}{(z-n)^2} 
\prod_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-r}.$$
which has the property that
$$\;\underset{z=q}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= {n-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-1-q}
\frac{1}{(1-q/n)^2}.$$
Residues sum to zero and we may evaluate with minus the
residue at $z=n$:
$$- n! \times n \times 
\left.\left(\prod_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-r}\right)'\right|_{z=n}
\\ = n!  \times n \times 
\left.\left(\prod_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-r}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{z-r}
\right)\right|_{z=n}
= n! \times n \times \frac{1}{n!} H_n = n \times H_n.$$
The sanity check goes through.
 Main computation 
Next we ask how many coupons appear $j$
times in this setting. We get the mixed GF
$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times {n\choose 1}
\times (m-1)! [z^{m-1}] 
\left(\exp(z)+(u-1)\frac{z^j}{j!}-1\right)^{n-1}.$$
Differentiate with respect to $u$ and set $u=1$ to get
$$\frac{1}{n^m} \times n(n-1)
\times (m-1)! [z^{m-1}] 
\left(\exp(z)-1\right)^{n-2} \frac{z^j}{j!}.$$
Summing we find
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{j!} \sum_{m\ge j+1}
\frac{1}{n^m} (m-1)! [z^{m-1-j}] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-2}
\\ = \frac{n(n-1)}{j!} \sum_{m\ge j+1}
\frac{1}{n^m} (m-1)! [z^{m-1-j}] 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} \exp(qz)
\\ = n(n-1) \sum_{m\ge j+1}
\frac{1}{n^m} {m-1\choose m-1-j}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} q^{m-1-j}
\\ = (n-1)\frac{1}{n^j} \sum_{m\ge 0}
\frac{1}{n^m} {m+j\choose m}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} q^m
\\ = (n-1) \frac{1}{n^j}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{1}{(1-q/n)^{j+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{j+1} n (n-1)
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{1}{(q-n)^{j+1}}.$$
To evaluate we introduce
$$f(z) = (n-2)! \frac{1}{(z-n)^{j+1}} 
\prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r}$$
which has the property that
$$\;\underset{z=q}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-q}
\frac{1}{(q-n)^{j+1}}.$$
Residues sum to zero and we may evaluate with minus the
residue at $z=n$ since the  residue at infinity is zero
also, and we obtain in terms of a derivative
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_j] =
(-1)^j \frac{n!}{j!} \left. 
\left[ \prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r}
\right]^{(j)} \right|_{z=n.}}$$
We  can use  this formula  to get  concrete values  for
fixed $j$. We find for singletons with $j=1$
$$-n! \left. \left[ \prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r} 
\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}
\right] \right|_{z=n.}
= -n! \times \frac{1}{n!} \times (-H_n + 1)$$
so that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_1] = H_n.}$$
Here  we have  added a  unique correction  term as  the
coupon  that  completes  the   set  also  counts  as  a
singleton.
Continuing with pairs, i.e. $j=2$,
$$\frac{1}{2} n! \left. \left[ \prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r} 
\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}\right)^2
+ \prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}
\right] \right|_{z=n.}$$
so that we obtain $\frac{1}{2} [(H_n-1)^2 + H^{(2)}_n-1]$ or
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_2] = \frac{1}{2} [ H_n^2 - 2 H_n + H^{(2)}_n].}$$
To conclude we do triples i.e. $j=3$. We need to differentiate
$$\prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r} 
\left[\left( \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}\right)^2
+ \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2} \right]$$
which gives
$$\prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r} \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}
\left[\left( \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}\right)^2
+ \sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2} \right]
\\ + \prod_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{z-r} 
\left[\left( 2\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{r-z}
\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(r-z)^2}\right)
+ 2\sum_{r=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(r-z)^3} \right]$$
Setting $z=n$ we get
$$-\frac{1}{6} (-(H_n-1) [(H_n-1)^2 + H^{(2)}_n-1]
- 2 (H_n-1) (H^{(2)}_n-1) - 2 (H^{(3)}_n - 1))$$
or
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_3] = \frac{1}{6}
((H_n-1) [(H_n-1)^2 + 3 (H^{(2)}_n-1)]
+ 2 (H^{(3)}_n - 1)).}$$
 Asymptotics 
For the asymptotics we get
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_1] \sim \log n + \gamma.}$$
as well as for $j=2$
$$\frac{1}{2} [\log^2 n + 2 \gamma \log n + \gamma^2 
- 2 \log n - 2 \gamma
+ \frac{\pi^2}{6}]$$
which is
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[C_2] \sim \frac{1}{2} \log^2 n + (\gamma - 1) \log n
+  \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2 - \gamma + \frac{\pi^2}{12}.}$$
The  case for  $j=3$  is left  to  the reader.  Apery's
constant appears.
 Addendum, Computer Algebra 
Using  a CAS  to  automate the  differentiation in  the
formula  for  $\mathrm{E}[C_j]$  we can  tackle  higher
values of $j$ e.g. $j=20$ is possible. We get for $j=4$
$$\mathrm{E}[C_4] =
\frac{1}{24} H_{n ,1}^{4}
-\frac{1}{6} H_{n ,1}^{3}
+\frac{1}{4} H_{n ,1}^{2} H_{n ,2}
-\frac{1}{2} H_{n ,1} H_{n ,2}
\\ +\frac{1}{3} H_{n ,1} H_{n ,3}
-\frac{1}{3} H_{n ,3}
+\frac{1}{8} H_{n ,2}^{2}
+\frac{1}{4} H_{n ,4}$$
and for $j=5$
$$\mathrm{E}[C_5] =
\frac{1}{6} H_{n ,2} H_{n ,3}+\frac{1}{12} H_{n ,1}^{3} H_{n ,2}
+\frac{1}{6} H_{n ,1}^{2} H_{n ,3}+\frac{1}{8} H_{n ,1} H_{n ,2}^{2}
+\frac{1}{4} H_{n ,1} H_{n ,4}\\+\frac{1}{5} H_{n ,5}
+\frac{1}{120} H_{n ,1}^{5}-\frac{1}{3} H_{n ,1} H_{n ,3}
-\frac{1}{8} H_{n ,2}^{2}\\-\frac{1}{4} H_{n ,1}^{2} H_{n ,2}
-\frac{1}{4} H_{n ,4}-\frac{1}{24} H_{n ,1}^{4}.$$
We have for the asymptotics for $j=3$
$$\mathrm{E}[C_3] \sim
\frac{\ln \! \left(n \right)^{3}}{6}
+\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \ln \! \left(n \right)^{2}
+\left(\frac{1}{2} \gamma^{2}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \pi^{2}\right)
\ln \! \left(n \right)\\+\frac{\gamma^{3}}{6}-\frac{\gamma^{2}}{2}
+\frac{\gamma  \,\pi^{2}}{12}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}
+\frac{\zeta \! \left(3\right)}{3}.$$
and for $j=4$
$$\mathrm{E}[C_4] \sim
\frac{\ln \! \left(n \right)^{4}}{24}+\left(-\frac{1}{6}
+\frac{\gamma}{6}\right) \ln \! \left(n \right)^{3}
+\left(-\frac{1}{2} \gamma +\frac{1}{4} \gamma^{2}
+\frac{1}{24} \pi^{2}\right) \ln \! \left(n \right)^{2}
\\ +\left(\frac{\gamma^{3}}{6}-\frac{\gamma^{2}}{2}
+\frac{\gamma  \,\pi^{2}}{12}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}
+\frac{\zeta \! \left(3\right)}{3}\right) \ln \! \left(n \right)
\\ +\frac{\pi^{4}}{160}-\frac{\zeta \! \left(3\right)}{3}
-\frac{\gamma  \,\pi^{2}}{12}-\frac{\gamma^{3}}{6}
+\frac{\gamma^{2} \pi^{2}}{24}
+\frac{\gamma  \zeta \! \left(3\right)}{3}
+\frac{\gamma^{4}}{24}.$$
Observe   that   adding   $\sum_{j\ge   1}   j   \times
\frac{1}{j!} \log^j  (n) \sim \log(n)  \times \exp(\log
n) =  n \times \log(n)$  which shows we  have accounted
for all coupons.
These were computed with the following code:

EX :=
proc(n,j)
option remember;
    (-1)^j*n!/j!
    * subs(z=n, diff(mul(1/(z-r), r=0..n-2), z$j));
end;

DV :=
proc(j)
option remember;
local prev, sbl;

    if j=0 then return A(z) fi;

    prev := DV(j-1);

    sbl :=
    [diff(A(z), z)=A(z)*B[1](z),
     seq(diff(B[q](z), z)=q*B[q+1](z), q=1..j)];
    subs(sbl, diff(prev, z));
end;

HX := (n,q) -> add(1/p^q, p=1..n);

EXDV :=
proc(n,j)
local core, sbl;

    core := simplify(DV(j)/A(z));

    sbl := [seq(B[q](z)=(-1)^q*(HX(n,q)-1), q=1..j)];

    (-1)^j/j!*subs(sbl, core);
end;


EXHM :=
proc(j)
local core, sbl;

    core := simplify(DV(j)/A(z));

    sbl := [seq(B[q](z)=(-1)^q*(H[n,q]-1), q=1..j)];

    expand((-1)^j/j!*subs(sbl, core));
end;

EXAS :=
proc(j)
local core, sbl;

    core := simplify(DV(j)/A(z));

    sbl := [B[1](z)=-(log(n)+gamma-1),
            seq(B[q](z)=(-1)^q*(Zeta(q)-1), q=2..j)];

    expand((-1)^j/j!*subs(sbl, core));
end;


Great  answer. (+1)
